# « Pan » dans « cravate à long pans »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

L'une des définitions du nom féminin [« régate » sur Wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/regate) est décrite ainsi :

> Cravate à long **pans**.

Je bute sur l'emploi de **pan** (nom masculin). Aucune définition dans l'[article correspondant du Larousse](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/pan/57533?q=pan#57198) ne paraît y correspondre ?

---

**Supplément à la suite des utilisateurs Laure et Zistoloen :**

Je m'aperçois que une cravate est proprement une étoffe tendue. Par contre, je ne saisis pas comment elle :
● flotte (la 2e définition offerte par Zistoloen) et
● peut être rabattu (Conformément au commentaire de Laure) et
● soulevé (Commentaire de Laure) ?

D'ailleurs, encore qu'il soit matériellement possible de rabattre et soulever une cravate et qu'une cravate peut flotter dans la brise, est-ce ses attributs les plus propres ? 
Principalement, on porte une cravate et on faire un nœud avec ça ? On ne fais ni flotter ni rabattre ni soulever une cravate hormis le nettoyage ?

Comment: De la page que tu donnes :  « Partie d'une étoffe tendue qui retombe, ou que l'on peut rabattre, soulever : *Les pans d'une nappe, d'une écharpe.* »

Comment: @Laure Quand bien même est-elle courte, ta remarque est une réponse. Aussi te suggéré-je d’en faire une “réponse” que Stack Exchange considérera comme telle, notamment par égard aux futurs utilisateurs.

Comment: @Laure: Merci. Je bloque encore. Ainsi, pourriez-vous répliquer à mon supplément dans mon OP ?

Comment: D’où diable vient cette définition de « cravate » ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la cravate a des longs pans et qu'ils ne sont pas tenus à la chemise par une épingle :  [image]
 ou coincés dans le pantalon ou par la veste :
[image]
les pans peuvent très bien être soulevés par un coup de vent, ce qui peut conduire le porteur de la cravate à les rabattre.
C'est ce qui pourrait se passer ici si l'homme se trouvait soudain dans un courant d'air :
[image]

Une cravate n'est pas forcément une étoffe tendue. Il a existé différentes formes de cravates à travers les siècles. Pour une histoire de la cravate voir [ce site](http://jf.gateau.pagesperso-orange.fr/histoire/histoire.htm).
 La « régate » est la forme de cravate la plus répandue de nos jours : ruban plus ou moins long qu'on noue autour du cou et dont le nœud laisse échapper deux pans verticaux superposés. 
[image]
On a donné ce nom à cette forme de cravate parce qu'elle rappelle la cravate que portaient les marins sur les bateaux de plaisance.

> La régate est la cravate la plus portée de nos jours et de ce fait, le
>   mot cravate lui est appliqué, rendant archaïque le terme régate. (Dictionnaire culturel en langue française, sld Alain Rey)

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant. J'ai plussoyé.

Answer (score 2):

Le Trésor de la langue française donne la réponse à ta question [ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pan) :

> 1. Partie tombante d'un vêtement, pouvant flotter.
> 2. a) Partie tombante d'une étoffe, qui peut flotter, ou que l'on peut rabattre ou soulever.

Sinon, une cravate peut effectivement flotter lors d'un coup de vent, être rabattue ou soulevée par quelqu'un. Une cravate, on la noue mais finalement faire un noeud avec revient à la manipuler, la soulever et la rabattre.

Comment: J'ai mis à jour ma réponse.

Comment: Je vous suis reconnaissant. J'ai plussoyé.